# Migrate single fields into field collection

Tags: entities

Really enjoy this module, I use it (nearly) in all my projects.
As many people I'm facing the following problem : my client's requirement have changed and I have to create a field collection from 4 existing single fields (vimeo URL, file, image and long text). Hundreds of nodes have already been created, no way to start over. This is a production site with many users.
What options do I have ?